# Is there an equivalent in C for C++ templates?

Tags: c

In the code I am writing I need `foo(int, char*)` and `foo(int, int)` functions.

If I was coding this in C++ I would use templates. Is there any equivalent for C? Or should I use void pointers? How?

Comment: Sometimes you can also use macros to emulate template behaviour.

Comment: In C++ you would use overriding not templates for that

Comment: @Motti overloading, isn't it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do that.
In C there are no overloads, one function, one name, you'll need to use a type that supports all your needs, e.g. (void *)

Either that or do a `foo_int(int,int)` and a `foo_char(int, char*)`

Comment: I agree. The usual C solution consists of functionnames with type suffixes. famous example: atoi, atol, atoll (IIRC) and OpenGL glVector3f, glVector2f, glColor3f, ...

Comment: but if i use void* how can I then check what type the data is? there's no c isInteger and isCharPointer, right?

Comment: You can't. If you don't know what is it in advance you'll need to pass another parameter to distinguish. But thats kind of ugly, I'd implement `foo_int` and `foo_char`

Comment: The fact that the language does not have a specific facility for generic programming does not mean one cannot overcome this deficiency.

Answer (score 46):

I think the closest you can get in C to templates is some ugly macro code. For example, to define a simple function that returns twice its argument:

```
#define MAKE_DOUBLER(T)  \
    T doubler_##T(T x) { \
        return 2 * x;    \
    }

MAKE_DOUBLER(int)
MAKE_DOUBLER(float)
```

Note that since C doesn't have function overloading, you have to play tricks with the name of the function (the above makes both `doubler_int` and `doubler_float`, and you'll have to call them that way).

```
printf("%d\n", doubler_int(5));
printf("%f\n", doubler_float(12.3));
```

Comment: As an aside, the maintenance programmer who follows you (which may also be you) will *not* appreciate this technique. If you see a call to `doubler_int()` and don't know about the macro, how would you find that function? A search of the source code won't find it.

Comment: Where does one write MAKE_DOUBLER(int ) and MAKE_DOUBLER(float) ?

Comment: @ShehbazJaffer Anywhere you normally declare a function.

Comment: Some compilers won't like this - the #define is a precompiler so the function (macro textural data) will be inlined. You cannot literally inline functions within functions in visual studio. This may work with gcc however but not as an argument in the printf example. Templates are cleverer than #defines as the compiler can decide whether to inline like a #define or create a symbol to a new generated function as presented by the template - very, very powerful.

Comment: If you use a macro to substitute just the function body and not the header, the problem raised by Greg can be avoided.

e.g. `int doubler_int (int x) MAKE_DOUBLER (int)`

Answer (score 24):

Yes, there is. You can use type-generic expression in [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo_char_ptr(int a, char *b) {
  printf("Called int, char*.\n");
}

void foo_int(int a, int b) {
  printf("Called int, int.\n");
}

#define foo(a, b) _Generic((b), char*: foo_char_ptr, int: foo_int)(a, b)

int main() {
  foo(1, 1);
  foo(1, "foo");
}

// Output:
// Called int, int.
// Called int, char*.
```

Answer (score 10):

Templates can be realized using template headers.

Let foo.h like this:

```
#ifndef PREFIX
    #define PREFIX
#endif
#define CCAT2(x, y) x ## y
#define CCAT(x, y) CCAT2(x, y)
#define FN(x) CCAT(PREFIX, x)

#ifndef T
    #error Template argument missing.
#endif

void FN(foo)(int x, T t)
{
    // Whatever.
}


#undef T
#undef PREFIX
#undef CCAT2
#undef CCAT
#undef FN
```

To use it you can do:

```
#define T char*
#define PREFIX pchar_
#include "foo.h"

#define T int
#define PREFIX int_
#include "foo.h"
```

Now you have `pchar_foo()` and `int_foo()` which you can use.

The advantages of this is that if there is a build problem, you get line number in the template header instead of the compiler just saying the macro is wrong, and code completion works too in some IDEs.

The `PREFIX`, the `CCAT` and `FN` macros are very common so I extracted their definition into a separate header, and their undefinition to another one.

I implemented parts of the STL using this pattern for fun and use it in some of my C projects.

Comment: Clever, I like that you are just including the .h more than once.  Best answer

Answer (score 7):

Others have discussed the intrinsic limitation of c with regard to overloading. Note, however, that if you can deduce which case is needed you can use varargs:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
foo(int, ...);
```

If you can't deduce it, you can pass an extra argument:

```
foo(int, char *spec, ...);
```

where `spec` tells the function what to expect in the subsequent arguments. Like the `printf` and `scanf` families of functions. In fact, you might find it convenient to reuse the printf/scanf conventions for specifying type, thus saving your users from having to lean another mini-language.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of void* you can also use a union to hold any type of data you need:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    union {
        char* char_ptr;
        int int_val;
        // etc...
    };
} foo_data;

void foo(foo_data data)
{
    switch (data.type) {
        case 0:
            printf("%s\n", data.char_ptr);
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("%i\n", data.int_val);
            break;
    }
}

void main()
{
    foo_data data;

    data.type = 0; data.char_ptr = "hello";
    foo(data);
    data.type = 1; data.int_val  = 12;
    foo(data);
}
```

Of course, you should create constants for the type values.

Comment: Was about to write this answer, but you had already done so.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `_Generic` from GCC. (Although this is NOT portable to other compilers)
http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html

Comment: It seems the answer by Mirek Rusin already suggests that. And why is it not portable? It's a C11 feature.

Comment: This has already been answered. Please do not post duplicate answers. Do you research properly before posting any answer here. Thanks

Comment: Rather disingenuous to post a link to 2012 blog about a feature published in 2011 complaining about compatibility,  7 years after...

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, Clang [was broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18857056/918959), it was fixed in Clang 3.8.0. The current version of Clang is 8