# Generic binary search tree in C

Tags: c, generics, binary-tree, function-pointers, binary-search-tree

I have the implemented a binary search tree but I also want to make it generic. The code is the following:

```
typedef struct treeNode {
  int data;
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
} treeNode;
```

and the functions:

```
treeNode* FindMin(treeNode *node) {
  if(node==NULL) {
    /* There is no element in the tree */
    return NULL;
  }
  if(node->left) /* Go to the left sub tree to find the min element */
    return FindMin(node->left);
  else 
    return node;
}

treeNode * Insert(treeNode *node,int data) {
  if(node==NULL) {
    treeNode *temp;
    temp = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    temp -> data = data;
    temp -> left = temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
  }

  if(data > (node->data)) {
    node->right = Insert(node->right,data);
  }
  else if(data <= (node->data)) {
    node->left = Insert(node->left,data);
  }
/* Else there is nothing to do as the data is already in the tree. */
  return node;
}

treeNode * Delete(treeNode *node, int data) {
  treeNode *temp;
  if(node==NULL) {
    printf("Element Not Found");
  }
  else if(data < node->data) {
    node->left = Delete(node->left, data);
  }
  else if(data > node->data) {
    node->right = Delete(node->right, data);
  }
  else {
    /* Now We can delete this node and replace with either minimum element 
       in the right sub tree or maximum element in the left subtree */
    if(node->right && node->left) {
        /* Here we will replace with minimum element in the right sub tree */
        temp = FindMin(node->right);
        node -> data = temp->data; 
        /* As we replaced it with some other node, we have to delete that node */
        node -> right = Delete(node->right,temp->data);
    }
    else {
        /* If there is only one or zero children then we can directly 
            remove it from the tree and connect its parent to its child */
        temp = node;
        if(node->left == NULL)
            node = node->right;
        else if(node->right == NULL)
            node = node->left;
        free(temp); /* temp is longer required */ 
    }
}
  return node;

}

void PrintInorder(treeNode *node) {
  if (node != NULL) {
    PrintInorder(node->left);
    printf("%d ",node->data);
    PrintInorder(node->right);
  }
}
```

First thing is to change in the struct

```
int data;
```

to

```
void *data;
```

Edited with more code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct treeNode {
  void *data;
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
}treeNode;

treeNode * Insert(treeNode *node, void *data, int sizeOfType, int (*compare) (void *arg1, void *arg2)) { 
  if(node==NULL) {
    treeNode *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp->data = malloc(sizeOfType);
    memcpy(temp->data, data, sizeOfType);
    temp -> left = temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
  }

  if(compare(data, node->data) == 1) {
    node->right = Insert(node->right, data, sizeof(int), compare(data, node->data));
  }
  else if(compare(data, node->data) == -1 || compare(data, node->data) == 0) {
    node->left = Insert(node->left, data, sizeof(int), compare(data, node->data));
  }
  return node;
}

void print(void* a) { 
printf("%d ",*(int*)a); 
}

void InorderGeneric(treeNode *node, void(*p)(void *)) { 
  if (node != NULL) {                                
    InorderGeneric(node->left, p);
    p(node->data);  
    InorderGeneric(node->right, p); 
  }
}

int int_sorter( void *first_arg, void *second_arg ) {
  int first = *(int*)first_arg;
  int second = *(int*)second_arg;
  if ( first < second ) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if ( first == second ) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  treeNode *root = NULL;
  int item;
  void *v;

  printf("Add nodes in binary tree:\n");
  while (scanf("%d ", &item) == 1) {
    v = &item;
    root = Insert(root, v, sizeof(int), int_sorter);
  }

  printf("\n---Initial tree---\n");
  printf("IN-order walk of tree:\n");
  InorderGeneric(root, print);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

You're going to need to create a comparison function for each data type that's used and pass a function pointer to each function that needs to know if two pieces of data are equal or greater/less than each other. Only this function will have to know the internal data type.

This function would look like:

```
int compare_X(const void *d1, const void *d2)
```

And the function should return 0 if the two objects are equal, less than 0 if the object pointed to by d1 is smaller, or greater than 0 otherwise. You would have a range of these functions, such as `compare_int`, `compare_double`, etc, depending on the type of data you're storing in a specific tree.

You would then add this argument to the functions the need to compare two objects:

```
int (*cpm_fptr)(const void *, const void *)
```

Now for example in `Insert`, `if(data > (node->data))` would become:

```
if (cmp_fptr(data, node->data) > 0) /* data > node->data */
```

Also:

```
if (cmp_fptr(data, node->data) == 0) /* data == node->data */

if (cmp_fptr(data, node->data) < 0) /* data < node->data */
```

The signature of `Insert` would now look like:

```
treeNode * Insert(treeNode *node, int data, 
                  int (*cpm_fptr)(const void *, const void *))
```

And if your internal type was `int`, you might call it like:

```
Insert(node, my_int, compare_int);
```

This is how functions like `bsearch` and `qsort` are able to operate on data of any type.

Comment: thank you for your answer. See my new edit in my post and tell if I am doing it correct.

Comment: @kokosg: It might be a better idea to check if the return value of `compare` is `< 0` instead of `== -1` and `> 0` instead of `== 1`, since the comparison function for an `int` could simply be: `*(int*)d1 - *(int*)d2`. Your `else if` could also simply become an `else`. Also, consider using the type `size_t` for `sizeOfType`, rather than `int`.

Comment: I edited again with the new updated code. What am I missing here?

Comment: @kokosg: You're still using `sizeof(int)` in your `Insert` calls.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a `union` to represent the data you want to store, along with information of the type the union represents at any time. Something like below:

```
typedef struct _generic_data {
    union {
        int         i;              /* Integer */
        long        l;              /* Long */
        float       f;              /* floating point */
        double      d;              /* double precision floating point */
        char        c;              /* char */
        char        *s;             /* c string */
        struct {
            void        *blob;      /* Arbitrary blog of binary data */
            int         size;       /* Size of this blob */
        }           b;              /* You may not really need it
                                     * So you can get rid of this struct
                                     * if you want.
                                     */
    } value;                        /* To access the above values */
    int type_id;                    /* To identify which data type is actually 
                                     * being stored in this generic data struct
                                     */
} generic_data;
```

Of course you should also have the corresponding `unsigned` types for the above types too for completeness sake. Set `type_id` to distinctly identify elements. For example:

```
const int char_type_id = 1;
const int long_type_id = 2;
....
const int blob_type_id = 10;
const int error_type_id = -42;
```

and so on, so that the following holds for `generic_data gd;`

- When `gd.type_id == char_type_id`, then `gd.value.c` is the valid value.
- Same for the rest of the types.

So now, your `Node` would look like:

```
typedef struct treeNode {
  generic_data*   data;
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treeNode *right;
} treeNode;
```

You would need to modify your functions as

```
treeNode * Insert(treeNode *node, generic_data* data);
treeNode * Delete(treeNode *node, generic_data* data);
```

You would also need a function which is able to compare between two `generic_data` values. Something like this:

```
long compare_generic(generic_data* lhs, generic_data* rhs) {
    if ( lhs == NULL || rhs == NULL ) {
        return error_type_id;
    }
    if ( lhs->type_id != rhs->type_id ) {
        /*
         * ERROR: Trying to compare two different types.
         * Do appropriate error handling here.
         * return some eror code.
         */
        return error_type_id;
    }
    switch( lhs->type_id ) {
        case char_type_id: return (long)(lhs->value.c - rhs.value.c); break;
        case int_type_id:  return (long)(lhs->value.i - rhs.value.i); break;
        /*
         * Something similarly logical for long, float, double.
         * The basic idea if this function returns 0 
         *
         * void *blob allows you to store arbitrary binary data. You 
         * may not need it, but if you do, there should be some way to
         * compare between the two.
         */
        default:
            /*
             * No type_id matches.
             * Handle this error case.
             * return some error code.
             */
            return error_type_id;
            break; /* Just a habbit to always have a break so that
                    * you don't have to deal with special cases.
                    */
    }
}
```

This would be used to replace your existing code as below:

- `if(data < node->data)` to this  : `if ( compare_generic( data, node->data ) < 0 )`
- `if(data > node->data)` to this  : `if ( compare_generic( data, node->data ) > 0 )`
- `if(data == node->data)` to this : `if ( compare_generic( data, node->data ) == 0 )`

You would now have to be extra careful in accessing your values.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this to be in C, you'll need a little more sophisticated approach (storing the type of the data in the tree in a variable and performing type-casts wherever necessary).

However, if you decide to do the same in C++, you can use Templates. There are numerous examples on Templates available on the web.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want this to be in C. I approach the function insert as you said but doesn't work.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873850/is-there-a-equivalent-in-c-for-c-templates