# C11 _Generic: how to deal with string literals?

Tags: c, clang, c11

Using the `_Generic` feature in C11, how do you deal with string literals?

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define foo(x) _Generic((x), char *: puts(x))

int main()
{
    foo("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

gives this error on clang:

```
controlling expression type 'char [14]' not compatible with any generic association type
```

Replacing `char *` with `char[]` gives me

```
error: type 'char []' in generic association incomplete
```

The only ways (to my knowledge) of getting this to compile are:

1. Cast the string literal to an appropriate type. This is ugly and (in my view) defeats the point of `_Generic` in the first place.
2. Use `char[14]` as the type specifier. You have *got* to be kidding me...

My assumption was that arrays would decay to pointers when passed to `_Generic`, but evidently not. So, how *do* I use `_Generic` with string literals? Are those the only two options?

I'm using *clang* 3.2 on Debian. Unfortunately, it's the only compiler I have access to that supports this feature, so I can't tell if it's a compiler bug or not.

Comment: Note that the [N2176 draft for the upcoming C17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) requires array-to-pointer decay of the controlling expression of generic selections in 6.5.1.1, so string literals would be treated as char*:

_"The type of the controlling expression is the type of the expression as if it had undergone an lvalue conversion (footnote: lvalue conversion drops type qualifiers), array to pointer conversion, or function to pointer conversion."_

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define foo(x) _Generic((0,x), char*: puts(x))

int main()
{
    foo("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and produces:

```
$ clang t.c && ./a.out 
Hello, world!
```

It is somewhat lame, but I did not find any better way to make `x` decay to a pointer to char nor to match its type in the fuzzy fashion that you require, with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn).

According to [this blog post by Jens Gustedt](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/the-controlling-expression-of-_generic/), GCC's behavior is different (in GCC, strings automatically decay to pointer in a `_Generic` context, apparently).

By the way, in C, the type of a string literal is array of `char`, not of `const char`. Rejecting `char []` as *type-name* in a *generic-association* is not a compiler bug:

> A generic selection shall have no more than one default generic association. The type name in a generic association shall specify a **complete** object type other than a variably modified type. (6.5.1.1:2 with my emphasis)

Comment: Thank you, not a bad suggestion, if annoying. About `char` versus `const char`: yup, but `_Generic` adds `const` fuzzily, so I thought I'd take advantage of that. I'll edit the example. Cheers!

Comment: @MichaelRawson 6.5.1.1 continues: “If a generic selection has a generic association with a type name that is **compatible** with the type of the controlling expression, then the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in that generic association.” and `const char *` is not compatible with `char *`. I would not expect any const-fuzziness. My clang does not allow me any.

Comment: my apologies, I must have missed an asterisk somewhere or something. `clang` behaves as you (and the standard) describe.

Answer (score 15):

I have figured out a way to avoid using the clever `(0,x)` trick.

If you use a string literal the type is `char[s]` , where `s` is the size of the string literal.

How do you get that size?, use `sizeof` operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Test( x )   _Generic( ( x ) ,   char*: puts ,                   \
                                        const char*: puts ,             \
                                        const char[sizeof( x )]: puts , \
                                        char[sizeof( x )]: puts )( x )

int main(void) 
{

    char str[] = "This" ;
    Test( str ) ;

    Test( "works" ) ;

    char str2[10] = "!!!" ;
    Test( str2 ) ;

return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling it with clang and Pelles and it worked.

The only problem you still have to cast variable length arrays.

After trying some more I found another analogue way of doing what 
[Pascal Cuoq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18857389/4082723) did, use `&*` operators:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define foo(x) _Generic( ( &*(x) ), char*: puts , const char*: puts )( x )

int main()
{
    foo("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&*` is another “do nothing” context that, like `0,` forces pointer decay, but it won't work if `x` is not a pointer (say if you want to use `_Generic` for both floats and string literals). I am quite impressed by your use of `sizeof` though.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You're right, (0,x) is the only way. I only did all of this because the compiler gives me a warning: *Expression with no effect removed.* if I use (0,x).

Comment: Well if the statement that precedes the `_Generic` happens to be an expression, you can move it into the `_Generic`, transforming, say, `printf("hello world\n"); _Generic(x, …)` into `_Generic((printf("hello world\n"), x), …)`. You might also want to try whether `(((void)0), x)` makes the intent clear to the compiler.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yup `( void )0` did it. I also tried your way on clang online http://gcc.godbolt.org/ and it gave an error, but changing the expression a little: `_Generic( ( (0,x)+0 )` solved the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't *& work correctly for all types, also non pointer?

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour of Clang was [**incorrect** (C11 Defect report 481)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_481) until [3.7.1](https://godbolt.org/z/NXQmP-). It was fixed in [Clang 3.8.0, released on March 8, 2016](https://godbolt.org/z/3Nuy3j).

The Committee response to the DR 481 says the following:

> This paper elicited a long and productive discussion. The committee agrees with the author of the `_Generic` proposal that **the intent was that selecting on qualified types was explicitly to be avoided as was selecting on arrays by size**. The intent of `_Generic` was to give C a mechanism to somewhat express the notion of “overloaded function” found in C++, and in particular a possible mechanism for implementors to use to implement the atomic type generic functions from section 7.17.7.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Sad they changed it. Matching with sizeof like @2501 suggested would've been awesome. as it would've allowed the passing of the size of the array, effectively preventing pointer decay and all the potential bugs associated.