# Compatible types and ignoring top-level qualifiers in the C type system

Tags: c, generics, language-lawyer, type-systems

This is a multi-part question.

I've been trying to understand the C type system. First the C standard 
mentions the term "compatible type" a lot so I tried to understand that.
The definition seems to be quite spread out, but from what I found:

> 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type    1 Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional rules for determining
>   whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type
>   specifiers, in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.6 for
>   declarators.55) Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types
>   declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags
>   and members satisfy the following requirements: If one is declared
>   with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag. If both are
>   completed anywhere within their respective translation units, then the
>   following additional requirements apply: there shall be a one-to-one
>   correspondence between their members such that each pair of
>   corresponding members are declared with compatible types; if one
>   member of the pair is declared with an alignment specifier, the other
>   is declared with an equivalent alignment specifier; and if one member
>   of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared with the
>   same name. For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared
>   in the same order. For two structures or unions, corresponding
>   bit-fields shall have the same widths. For two enumerations,
>   corresponding members shall have the same values.

```
REFS:
    6.7.2  short == short int == signed short == signed short int, etc.
    6.7.3
        10) For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect the specified type.
    6.7.6
        1.2)
            For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.
        2.6)
For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.
```

it appears to me that

1. Two types are compatible if they're the same if all their complete parts are the same.
2. (as a consequence of 1.) "Complete compatible types" effectively means "same types".

So first, I'd like to ask if my interpretation is accurate.

Second, `_Generic` selections in the standard are defined in terms of this notion of "compatible type":

> 6.5.1.1 Generic selection     2 A generic selection shall have no more than one default generic association. The type name in a generic
>   association shall specify a complete object type other than a variably
>   modified type. No two generic associations in the same generic
>   selection shall specify compatible types. The controlling expression
>   of a generic selection shall have type compatible with at most one of
>   the types named in its generic association list. If a generic
>   selection has no default generic association, its controlling
>   expression shall have type compatible with exactly one of the types
>   named in its generic association list.

but compilers appear to interpret it differently in regards to top level qualifiers:

```
$ $CC -x c -include stdio.h - <<<'int main(){puts( _Generic((int const){0}, int:"int", int const: "int const")); }' && ./a.out      #int with gcc, and int const with clang
```

It seems to me the clang interpretation is correct, however what's perplexing is that

```
$ $CC -x c -include stdio.h - <<<'int main(){puts( _Generic((int const)0, int:"int", int const: "int const")); }' && ./a.out
```

says `"int"` even on clang.

So my second question is what in the standard would be the basis for interpreting `(int const)0` as of type `int` and `(int const){0}` as of type `int const`?

Finally, in all of my compilers (tcc,gcc,clang) top level qualifiers appear to be ignored on all types in prototype type lists
when determining compatibility between fucntions or function pointers:

```
for CC in tcc gcc clang; do echo CC=$CC; $CC -x c  - <<<'int main(){ static void (*f)(int*), (*g)(int * restrict const volatile);  f=g; }' ; done #no complaints
```

but I couldn't find any mention of this in the standard, so my final question is:

Is ignoring top level qualifiers on types in prototype type lists standard-sactioned in the context of determining function-compatibility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatible type does not mean that they must be **exactly the same type for all uses**. Notice

```
struct foo *
```

in one translation unit is compatible with

```
struct foo *
```

if neither is a pointer to a complete type. However if the members of `foo` are defined even after there declarations then the definitions must match, otherwise the prior pointers will not be compatible!

Likewise a type and its `typedef` are compatible with each other.

But the compatibility does not require that the types are the same: an array can have an incomplete and a complete type and they're compatible with each other. In one translation unit you can declare

```
extern int a[];
```

and in another

```
int a[10];
```

and they're compatible types.

[C11 6.7.6p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p6):

> For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if **both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value**. If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.

Furthermore a VLA type can be a compatible type with a statically-dimensioned array - it is considered compatible always, if the element type is the same, but the behaviour will be undefined if the dimensions do not actually match when they're required.

---

As for `_Generic`, Clang is definitely at fault here. In fact this has been addressed in [Defect report 481](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_481), and it was deemed that Clang is consistently wrong and GCC is right; The standard was amended for C18 [as noted by ov2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9964991/ov2k). See also  [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55392218/9189599) for another case, this time arising from Clang not doing the lvalue conversion of an array to a pointer type.

`(const int){0}` does create an lvalue of type `const int` (a compound literal), but the subsequent lvalue conversion should drop the type qualifiers and the result should be `int`. In fact the `_Generic` selection should not be able to select any type that is `const`-qualified, so I think [compilers should issue a warning for even having the `const` qualifier there](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90253).

Comment: I think you edited away a little too much! It was good to explain the difference between the compound literal `(const int) {0}` and the cast `(const int) 0`. Even if the original motivation was screwy because of `_Generic()`, that was one of the things asked.

Answer (score 3):

Things are slightly more complicated because `_Generic()` has some extra rules and because you seem to have encountered a bug in clang that has now been fixed.

C18 (6.5.1.1 para 2) added some requirements to generic selection:

> The type of the controlling expression is the type of the expression as if it had undergone an lvalue conversion, 93) array to pointer conversion, or function to pointer conversion.

Footnote 93 states:

> lvalue conversion drops type qualifiers.

For your `_Generic((int const){0}, ...)` example, FreeBSD clang version 6.0.1 reports `int`.

Basically, generic selection is not a very good way to explore the concept of compatible types as it relates to type qualifiers due to the lvalue conversion of the controlling expression.

Comment: Thanks for digging this Q/A to the active list :D