# Implicit Pointer-To-Const-T conversion

Tags: c, constants, language-lawyer

I was wondering if the implicit conversion to a pointer to a const data type is somewhere defined in the C11 standard:

```
T x;
const T *p = &x;
```

A pointer to an object of type `T` is implicitly converted into a pointer to an object of type `const T`. Is this implicit conversion somewhere defined in the C11 standard? (I know that it makes sense to allow this and how useful it is. I'm just curious to know where it is defined in the standard)

Furthermore, is an implicit conversion from type `T**` to `const T**` forbidden according to C11?

```
T *p;
const T **pp = &p;
```

This is a well known problematic part and therefore GCC and LLVM/clang raise a warning. Still I'm wondering if this is allowed according to the C11 standard or not. I only found in §6.5.16.1P6 a comment that this should be a *constraint violation*. However, I do not see which constraint should be violated. Again I know that this should be prohibited and that this implicit conversion can lead to subtle problems. I'm just curious to know if this is (un)defined behaviour according to C11.

Again, my two questions are not about if this is good or not (which is answered multiple times here) but how/where the C11 standard defines this.

---

Just for the sake of completeness here is a link to why the second example is problematic: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html

Comment: Section 6.3.2.3 para 2 for the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A pointer to an object of type T is implicitely converted into a
>   pointer to an object of type const-T. Is this implicit conversion
>   somewhere defined in the C11 standard?

Yes. This implicit conversion is mandated by the standard.

[Paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4p3) of section [6.5.4 Cast Operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4) says that

> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the
>   constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit
>   cast.

and the referenced 6.5.16.1 under point 3 says:

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type,
>   and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
>   conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified
>   versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has
>   all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

Therefore the implicit conversion for `const T *p = &x;` holds because you're only adding qualifiers, not removing them.

`const T **pp = &p;` doesn't fall under this, so you need an explicit cast (C++ would allow `const T*const*pp = &p;` (the second const is needed) but C still wouldn't.)

The pointer conversion through an explicit cast isn't a problem as far as UB is concerned as long as the alignments match (which for pointers to differently qualified types they will) because 
[6.3.2.3p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7) guarantees that:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
>   Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a
>   pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed
>   byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the
>   size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the
>   object.

but you need to be mindful of accesses/dereferences which will be governed by the [strict aliasing rule](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:88)
>
> a type compatible with the effective type of the object, a qualified
>   version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object, a
>   type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
>   effective type of the object, a type that is the signed or unsigned
>   type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the
>   object, an aggregate or union type that includes one of the
>   aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a
>   member of a subaggregate or contained union), or a character type.

Comment: My first thought was also that §6.5.16.1 para 3 should  hold (at least for the first case). However, my mind got twisted by the wording: "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types". Does this mean `const T` and `T` are compatible types? According to my understanding they are not, and §6.7.3 para 10 says "For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type". Although this does not really fit since not both types are qualified.

Comment: Sorry for the second reply, but I ran out of characters ;) Can you elaborate why the second case does not fall under §6.5.16.1? I mean, if `const T` and `T` are compatible, then `const T*` and `T*` should be, and therefore §6.5.16.1 should hold for `const T**` and `T**`, too. Or am I missing something (I should probably take some rest and sleep over it, though).

Comment: @MaxMaier Type compatibility seems to be a very convolutely defined concept whose definition is spread throughout the standard (see my question on it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479461/compatible-types-and-ignoring-top-level-qualifiers-in-the-c-type-system) but essentially (as I understand it) compatible in the context of types means identical and identically qualified with the caveat that there might be incomplete pieces: `int` isn't compatible with `int const` but `int[] /*incomplete*/` is compatible with `int[42]` (naturally, this isn't transitive).

Comment: Uhh the last example is a neat one. Thanks for clarifying this!